# How to get an S3 object using a URL and the 2.x Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the 2.x AWS Java SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/index.html).  I need to get an S3 object using the friendly HTTP URL (e.g. `https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/key` or `https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucket/key`).

The old SDK included an `AmazonS3URI` class that could parse a URL and extract the bucket and key.  Does the 2.x SDK include similar functionality, or should I use Java's URI class to parse the URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a way to do it with the SDK yet, but [it might be available in the future](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/272).  In the meantime, you can write your own code using Java's `URI` class, or use `AmazonS3URI` from the old SDK and hope it keeps working.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I did using `URI` from `java.net`:

```java
URI uri = new URI(s3Url);

String bucketName = uri.getHost();

// remove the first "/"
String prefix = uri.getPath().substring(1);
```

Comment: That should work if the bucket name is in the host.  You'll have to add some more logic if you want to handle the case where the bucket name is in the path.

Comment: This is the use case for me: `s3://bucketName/path1/path2/path3/`

Comment: Using give lib from Amazon lib, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.html

Comment: @kidnan1991 AmazonS3URI does not exist in AWS SDK v2

Answer (score 1):

This [pull request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/pull/3874) adds this functionality to the SDK version 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the functionality of `AmazonS3URI`, but don't want to import the entire library, you can also copy the source code. It's apache licensed

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.java

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `S3Uri` class. This allows you to extract the S3-specific elements of an S3 or HTTPS URI that identifies the S3 Bucket. It's pretty simple. In one of my projects, I needed to pass the S3 URI of a CDK [S3 Asset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_assets.Asset.html) to the S3 [Transfer Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html) in a CDK custom resource. The `S3Uri` class made it simple:

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.create();
S3Utilities s3Utilities = s3Client.utilities();
S3Uri s3Uri = s3Utilities.parseUri(URI.create("s3://bucket/key"));
DownloadFileRequest downloadFileRequest =
            DownloadFileRequest.builder()
                    .getObjectRequest(b -> 
                           b.bucket(s3Uri.bucket().orElseThrow())
                            .key(s3Uri.key().orElseThrow()))
                    .destination(downloadLocation)
                    .build();
```

You can find [more details here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/s3-uri-parsing-is-now-available-in-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/).

Answer (score -1):

Expanding upon @Bao Pham's answer, using `new URI(s3Url)` requires adding a try/catch, while if you use URI.create(s3Url), you don't need it. I also found it useful to use a `S3ObjectId` out of the parsed parts for re-usability.

```
public class S3Url {
    public static S3ObjectId decode(String urlStr) {
        URI uri = URI.create(urlStr);
        return new S3ObjectId(uri.getHost(), uri.getPath().substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, S3ObjectId isn't available in version 2.x of the API.  And this solution assumes that the host name contains the bucket, which isn't always the case.